# A different behavior of user authentication when using Sitecore membership provider

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, membership-provider

I'm using the asp.net login control and a switcher to get my users to authenticate against an external database.  I am now explicitly referencing my membership provider.

Using switcher:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(ApplicantLogin.UserName));
Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, ApplicantLogin.Password)
```

Without using a switcher:

```
var userName = Membership.Providers["Extranet"].GetUserNameByEmail(ApplicantLogin.UserName);
var user = Membership.Providers["Extranet"].GetUser(userName, true)
Membership.Providers["Extranet"].ValidateUser(user.UserName, ApplicantLogin.Password)
```

where `Extranet` is defined in my web config.  Both examples seem to work, however, using my switcher once a user is validated and authenticated the user gets redirected to my URL defined as my `DestinationPageUrl`.

Without using the switcher the user gets authenticated but is not redirected for some reason. I'm not sure why this is the case.

If I do a response.redirect after the user is validated then nothing happens either.  It stays on the login page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the user is being authenticated when you are not using switcher? You can debug this by implementing the **OnAuthenticate Event**:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Once you are sure that the user is being properly authenticated, try implementing the **LoggedIn Event** and then add your **Response.Redirect()** call there:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have verified that the user is being authenticated.  I tried putting Response.Redirect in the LoggedIn event but it still doesn't redirect to the page I have specified.